# Python list append causes strange result

Tags: python, list

I have really strange problem. Here is the sample code:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    a = []
    b = []
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.a = [(1,2), (3,4)]
        self.b = self.a
        self.a.append((5,6))
        print self.b

SomeClass()
```

Print outputs [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)], but why, why result isn't [(1,2), (3,4)] ?
Do you know how can I have the old value of self.a in self.b?

Thank you!

Comment: Because b points to a, when you change a, you change b as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are assigning *the same list* to `self.b`, not a copy.

If you wanted `self.b` to refer to a copy of the list, create one using either `list()` or a full slice:

```
self.b = self.a[:]
```

or

```
self.b = list(self.a)
```

You can test this easily from the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> a = b = []  # two references to the same list
>>> a
[]
>>> a is b
True
>>> a.append(42)
>>> b
[42]
>>> b = a[:]  # create a copy
>>> a.append(3.14)
>>> a
[42, 3.14]
>>> b
[42]
>>> a is b
False
```

Comment: Just to add the second method self.b = list(self.a), please add this also to the answer.

Answer (score 7):

As many have already mentioned it, you end up having *two* references on the *same* list. Modifying the list by one reference of by the other just modify *the* list.

Here is an illustration to make things more clear if needed:

[image: Shared reference]

- Step "A" is just after

  ```
  self.a = [(1,2), (3,4)]
  ```
- Step "A" is just after

  ```
  self.b = self.a
  ```
- Step "C" is just after

  ```
  self.a.append((5,6))
  ```

Comment: How did you generate these images?

Answer (score 2):

`self.b = self.a` isn't copying the list. It's assigning the reference to that list, so both attributes point at the same object. If you modify it via one reference, you'll see the change via the other one too.

You can use `copy.copy(the_list)` to get the proper copy. Or `copy.deepcopy(the_list)` if you need the references below also updated.

Comment: List objects don't have a `.copy` method

Comment: @Blender I guess he meant copy.copy(listname)

Comment: Yes, sorry could be more explicit. Edited now.

Answer (score 1):

dicts in python share the same memory space when you assign them to each other.

for more information on this see:
http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list

Comment: These are lists, not dictionaries. Lists do *not* have a `.copy()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Because `self.a` and `self.b` are actually references to the same list object.

If you want to modify one without changing the other, try this

```
class SomeClass(object):
    # a = []
    # b = [] # these two class member not necessary in this code
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.a = [(1,2), (3,4)]
        self.b = list(self.a) # copy to a new list
        self.a.append((5,6))
        print self.b

SomeClass()
```